# Interrupted encryption using Windows 7 BitLocker

Tags: windows-7, encryption, bitlocker

Can anyone help me please?

While I was encrypting my hard drive with Windows 7's BitLocker, I accidentally pressed the "Cancel" button, and now my hard drive won't accept my password.

Is there any way I can open it without damaging my files?

Thank you.

Comment: In the future, to encrypt your hard drive, use TrueCrypt.org instead (it doesn't have any known back doors and is open source):  http://www.truecrypt.org/

Comment: Can you be more explicit on what password the machine will not accept?  Bitlocker password, user account login password, etc.

Comment: it wont accept the bitocker password .